# Call Ninja Forms submit from javascrsipt

Tags: javascript, barcode, ninja-forms

I am trying to implement a bar code reader to a site that will get the users name and email from a bar code.

I would like if the barcode is read successfully to submit that data to a ninja forms form.

I know that the from data can be populated but I can't figure out how to trigger a submit event to ninja forms from a javascript call.